# Get most recently added file from Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script to search for the most recently added csv file to a google drive folder and add the contents to the last row of a "master sheet". Unfortunately the name of the csv file is not the same each time it gets placed in the drive folder so all I have to base the search on is the last file added.

I am getting an error which state:

"TypeError: Cannot find function hasNext in object Masergy Reports. (line 7, file "Code")"

Appreciate any help to solve this issue.

```
function importData()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1FldzyMKoQnbsqNxCYUZsizxVLShHrLBq_llJnu2so9o");
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : '1vzOduvWFCQGZYFuq_AKUY4NfDb2dW5fB';//default folderID
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = fldr.getFilesByType('text/csv');
  while (fldr.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getFilesByType('text/csv');
    if(fileType.match(files))
    {
      var csvstr=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      var csvData=Utilities.parseCsv(csvstr);
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MasergyReports");
      var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      file.setName(filename.slice(0,-3) + 'old');  //the .old files won't pass the file re filter next time. 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `var files = fldr.getFilesByType('text/csv');   while (fldr.hasNext())` Check variable names. `Cannot find function ... in object ...` is a big clue here that the object you named isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: @sinaraheneba any tips on what I need to change in my code to get it working?

Comment: You are trying to iterate through the folder object, not the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues:

- Your `folderID` variable seems overcomplicated, why check if it's undefined when you're defining it in that line?
- You're trying to iterate through your folder object rather than files in your `while` statement.
- `file.getFilesByType()` is not a valid method.
- `fileType` is not defined but you're using it in your `if` statement.
- Since your `filename` variable isn't valid, neither is your `setName()` statement.
- Setting the name will not change the file type, you need to add a line in your `if` statement to check filenames for your '.old' pattern.

---

#### Modified Code:

Just define `var folderID` with the ID alone, there's no reason to check if it's undefined because you're defining it anyway:

```
var folderID = '1vzOduvWFCQGZYFuq_AKUY4NfDb2dW5fB';
```

You should be iterating through your variable `files`, not `fldr`:

```
while (files.hasNext())
```

Alter `var fileName` to actually get the file name of each file:

```
var fileName = file.getName();
```

Change your `if` statement to get the content type of the file, rather than trying to define it in `var filename`. Also added a check for file names ending with '.old' to make sure we're only processing new files:

```
if(file.getBlob().getContentType() === "text/csv" && !fileName.match(/.old/))
```

Use our new `var fileName` instead in your `setName()` statement:

```
file.setName(fileName.slice(0,-3) + ".old");
```

---

#### Example:

```
function importData()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1FldzyMKoQnbsqNxCYUZsizxVLShHrLBq_llJnu2so9o");
  var folderID = '1vzOduvWFCQGZYFuq_AKUY4NfDb2dW5fB';
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = fldr.getFilesByType('text/csv');
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    if(file.getBlob().getContentType() === "text/csv" && !fileName.match(/.old/))
    {
      var csvstr=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      var csvData=Utilities.parseCsv(csvstr);
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MasergyReports");
      var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
      sheet.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      file.setName(fileName.slice(0,-3) + "old");  //the .old files won't pass the file re filter next time. 
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### References

- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)
- [`blob.getContentType()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getContentType())
- [`file.getName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getname)

Comment: Thanks @ross! That seems to work, however it's copying contents from all the csv files in the folder, not just the most recent. Do I need to change the script to find anything which is not marked as "old"?

Comment: Yes - changing the last 3 characters of the file name will not change the file type in Google Drive. I've added a check to the `if` statement for you.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Ross!

Comment: No problem, if the answer provided fixed your problem please mark it as accepted. This may help future users to find a solution faster when searching, but is not mandatory.

Comment: Note to future users: Don't forget to update line 15 `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MasergyReports");` to the name of your sheet (e.g., "Sheet1"), otherwise it'll throw an error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getLastRow')` 